# Como conecto express a wampserver?

Tags: express, wampserver

Estoy creando un backend con express, sin embargo, quiero utilizar WAMP server como servidor, ya que solo quiero utilizar express como un sistema de rutas. He estado investigando y no encuentro algo similar al tema. No necesito levantar un servidor con node, solo cómo realizar una llamada a una api con express para mostrarla en en el DOM.

Comment: *"No necesito levantar un servidor con Node"* y *"cómo realizar una llamada a una API con Express"* son mutuamente excluyentes. Express levanta un servidor con Node. Por otro lado, si tienes WAMP y quieres consumir una API, podrías usar PHP para este cometido.

Comment: Entonces no hay alguna forma de utilizar express con wamp?

Comment: Otra cosa es que configures Apache como proxy reverso para que derive las peticiones a tu aplicación Express y viceversa. De hecho, es la forma correcta de implementar una aplicación de NodeJS. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentarlo